# Validating schema locally with schemas from confluent schema registry

Tags: java, json, apache-kafka, jsonschema, confluent-schema-registry

Previously, I used `SchemaLoader` to load json schema files I had locally and validated JSON objects against them. Some of my schemas have refs to other local files.

I'm now migrating to the confluent schema registry and I've registered my schemas in the registry. Using `io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient`, I am able to query for the latest schema metadata for a particular subject and get the schema iteslf, references, etc.

However, it's unclear to me how to use `org.everit.json.schema.loader.SchemaLoader` (or anything else that can validate messages) to load the schema text and have a schema ready.  When I run this code, the last line gets an exception becuase it doesn't understand the `#ref` in the top level schema. The schema that comes from the registry has the `references` populated, but I'm not sure how to plug them in to the SchemaLoader.

`java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: RefSchema1.schema.json`

```
CachedSchemaRegistryClient registryClient = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(schemaRegistryUrl, 10);
System.out.println("Schema mode: " + registryClient.getMode());
var schemaMetaData = registryClient.getLatestSchemaMetadata(SCHEMA_SUBJECT);

System.out.println("analysis output schema ID: " + schemaMetaData.getId());
System.out.println("analysis output schema Version: " + schemaMetaData.getVersion());
System.out.println("analysis output schema: " + schemaMetaData.getSchema());
System.out.println("analysis output schema type: " + schemaMetaData.getSchemaType());
System.out.println("analysis output schema refs: " + schemaMetaData.getReferences());

var schemaObj = new JSONObject(schemaMetaData.getSchema());
Schema schema = SchemaLoader.load(schemaObj);
```

Another odd thing happenign is taht when I call registryClient.getSchemaById() using the id from the schema meata data, I get an "Invalid schema" exception for the schema.

Comment: Hi , were you able to figure this out? I have a same problem still..